# Why is there extra whitespace after newline when pasting using Screen?

Tags: vim, whitespace, gnu-screen

I am using screen to copy code that I am viewing using Vim from one window to another window currently editing a file with Vim. Unfortunately, when pasting onto the second window I get increasingly more white space to the left of my input after every newline. How is this whitespace finding its way onto my buffer?

I've attempted to turn off auto indenting in case Vim was adding the extra whitespace, but the problem persists.

Here is information that might be pertinent:

- OSx 10.6.8
- Both files are Unix style.
- Screen version: 4.00.03
- Vim version: 7.3
- Underlying terminal type is: xterm-color

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you copying using the mouse or some other non-vim ways? If yes you must do `:set paste` before pasting and `:set nopaste` after. See `:h pastetoggle` for a quick mapping.

If all your vim sessions are local and Vim supports it (`:echo has('clipboard')<CR>` should echo `1`), you should use your system clipboard: `"+y` to yank and `"+p` to paste without that pesky indenting.

Or, better, open your files in the same Vim session.

Comment: I am not using Vim to copy or paste. I am using Screen to to do so. I can definitely fix the problem by opening  the files in the same Vim session, but I find this problem interesting and would like to get to the bottom of it. Also, what do you mean by local exactly? As in the same host?

Comment: The problem is paste mode. Do `:set paste` before pasting, and the problem will be gone.

Comment: Yes, on the same host. From Vim's point of view pasting from screen or with `Cmd+v` is the same: the text is inserted char by char and line by line (but very quickly) and Vim applies formating and indenting. Use `"+y` and `"+p`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the `listchars` and the `eol`
Vim add a character at the end of line, some user add for example ↲

To remove this extra char you need to not set eop in listchars, for example:

```
set listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:-,extends:>,nbsp:\ ,precedes:<
```

tab will be replace by spaces, trailing spaces will appear with -, etc...

As eol is not present, it won't be display, this will fix your issue